# Error to migrate SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration

Hey Guys

I need help
I'm migrating data from SQL Server to Oracle by "Migrate to Oracle" from SQL Developer and, after I executed, appear an window with error message

**Migration actions have failed check the migration reports for details. :

Capture

Enterprise Capture

Capture failed. Refer to MIGRLOG table in the repository for details**

But I executed the privileges command

`GRANT connect, resource, create session, create view TO Merkel IDENTIFIED BY Merkel`

But the error still persist

How I fix it ?

Comment: And, what does the MIGRLOG table in the repository show?

Comment: Sorrry, but where I see the MIGRLOG table ?

Comment: also, it sounds like an issue on the SQL Server side - make sure  your SQL Server connection is using a highly priv user that has access to everything you want to move over

Comment: in your oracle database, we create a repository, it looks like it's in your MERKEL schema

Comment: I create a connection SQL Server, in SQL Developer, by "sa" user.

Comment: I created and associated the repository in Merkel schema.

Comment: so SELECT * FROM merkel.migrlog; on your Oracle DB

Comment: So I executed and return anyone line, MIGRLOG is empty.

Comment: Are you really migrating to an unsupported Oracle version (10g)?

Comment: I'm migrating to Oracle 10G

Comment: oh, you can't migrate to 10g, lowest version we support is 11gR2

Comment: So, I tried run it directly by Server Database, it's there the Oracle Client is version 11g2, and still persist that same error

Comment: I was executing of my machine as test, but in the server have the Oracle 11g2, I executed for there and appear that same error

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer migration repository also required MATERIALIZED VIEW privileges.

I would follow these steps.

1) Using sys or system in your Oracle 11g database to run the following

GRANT connect, resource, create session, create view, create materialized view TO Merkel2 IDENTIFIED BY Merkel2;

2) Create a SQL Developer connection to Merkel2.
3) Associate the migration repository with Merkel2.
4) Verify the migration repository is valid.

Browse your Merkel2 connection and verify that the packages and their package bodies are valid.

5) Attempt the migration again.
Regards,
Dermot